How can I make an http request using cookies on Flutter web using Dio (or any other library)?
We have Secure HttpOnly cookies that we need to send in a request to our backend.  We expose cookies to the domain example.com at the same time, and normally  digest cookies by our authorization portal and keycloak on domains auth.example.com and keycloak.example.com accordingly. We use the Dio library. The project is to be built only for the web. Any alternative to Dio?
We tried to use CookieJar, as in the example
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';

void main() async {
  var dio = Dio();

  var cookieJar = CookieJar();

  dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));

  var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com'); 
  cookieJar.saveFromResponse(uri, [
    Cookie('session_id', 'your_session_value')
      ..httpOnly = true
      ..secure = true,
  ]);

  var response = await dio.get('https://example.com/user-profile');
  print(response.data);

  var cookies = cookieJar.loadForRequest(uri);
  print(cookies); 
}


There is a simple solution that will not suit everyone, but in our situation it is enough. We use a simple wrapper over JS function in Dart
request.dart
import 'dart:js_interop';

@JS('makeRequest')
external JSPromise<JSString> makeRequest(
    String url, String method, String body);

Future<String> FetchString(String url,
    {String method = "GET", String body = ""}) async {
  JSString x = await makeRequest(url, method, body).toDart;
  return x.toString();
}

lib.js
async function makeRequest(url, method, body) {
  try {
    var response;
    if (method === "GET" || method === "HEAD") {
      response = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        credentials: "include",
      });
    } else {
      response = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: body,
      });
    }
    const text = await response.text();
    return text;
  } catch (error) {
    return `Error: ${error.message}`;
  }
}

web/index.html
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://static.example.com/lib.js"></script>
</head>

This code is far from ideal, it needs to be adapted to your situation, but it illustrates the approach to solving the problem
See also: https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop
